# Load ResourceBundle by Name

Tags: java, internationalization, resourcebundle, java-platform-module-system

From inside a named module, how do I get a resource bundle contained in a (potentially different) named module by the resource bundle's name? How would I implement something like `ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(String bundleBaseName, String moduleName)`?

I know the answer in some special cases:

- Resource bundles contained inside *the same module* as the loader code can be loaded with `ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleBaseName)`.
- If `bundleBaseName` is *known at compile time*, e.g. "com.vendor.bar.BarResource", then the provider module can do `provides com.vendor.bar.spi.BarResourceProvider with com.vendor.bar.spi.BarResourceProviderImpl`, the loader module can do `uses com.vendor.bar.spi.BarResourceProvider` and load the resource bundle with `ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.vendor.bar.BarResource")`.

I know that getting something by name is an operation that can fail. But when the resource bundle is contained in a module that is part of the application, then I would like to be able to load it.